# Passing multiple destinations as array to distance matrix api

Tags: react-native, google-distancematrix-api

I am calling distance-matrix api with multiple destinations as array but I am getting only one Array as response

```
destinationrequestsample---> ["0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0", "0,0"]
```

```
export async function getStoreDistance(locationDetails) {
  console.log('stordistance', locationDetails);
  let destinationRequest = locationDetails.destinations.map(location => {
    return `${location.lat},${location.long}`;
  });
  return await axios
    .get(
      `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial
      &origins=${locationDetails.origins.map(function(locationDetail) {
        return locationDetail;
      })}
      &destinations=${destinationRequest}&key=************j****c`,
    )
    .then(function(response) {
      // handle success
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      // handle error
      return error;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put '|' this symbol between different latitudes and longitudes.
Something like this:

> destinations = 41.43206,-81.38992|-33.86748,151.20699

So, in your code you can simply achieve this with the help of join method:

```
let destinationRequest = locationDetails.destinations.map(location => {
   return `${location.lat},${location.long}`;
}).join('|');
```